# Hide a table column when a radio button is clicked with a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide a table column for two of my radios and to show for one. So far I have tried many solutions but non are functional.

here are my radios,

```
<input type='radio'  name='users' value='all' <?php if (isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == 'all')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> checked /> All Candidates<br> 
              <input type='radio'  name='users' value='approved' <?php if (isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == 'approved') echo ' checked="checked"';?> / > Approved Candidates<br>
              <input type='radio' id='show' name='users' value='unapproved'  <?php if (isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == 'unapproved')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> /> Unapproved Candidates<br><br> 
             <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"><br><br>
```

My column is

```
<th>Check for Approval <input type="checkbox" id="select_all"/> </th>
```

And here follows my jQuery,

```
 <script>
        $(function() {

            $(':radio' ).change(function(){

                var isChecked = $('#show').prop('checked');
                $('#select_all').toggle(isChecked);
            });

        });
            </script>
```

On applying this ,what I have received so far is on clicking the radio button only the checkbox in the table header goes off for two of my radios but submit button makes that appear again. So no luck yet on this. Hope to find some solution regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery to hide the nth-child if it will always be the same column.

`$('th:nth-child(2),td:nth-child(2)').hide()`

Comment: Thanks for the concern. Yes its always the same column but I need to show this for the third table i.e. for 'unapproved'. How this can be implemented?

Comment: It hides the column completely for all three radio button selection. This doesn't solves the issue. Is there anyway to implement 'hide' for only two radios @CumminUp07

Comment: so you need it to hide the column when the unapproved radio is selected and show it when a different is selected? like this https://jsfiddle.net/xhf7a6fg/

Comment: Sorry for being late on your response..Thanks mate.. its working.. I just swapped the function name. But now I have a few questions regarding same, first its not responding on "submit" button click  i.e. when radio selected and clicked on submit its showing the original version of it.. so how can I put in the same implementation with"radio + submit" button. Secondly,  when going back to other radio selection its giving different tables for different radio selection i.e. "approved" shows all list and "unapproved " shows approved list. May I have some light on this.

Comment: Basically only the table column hide/show is executing but not MySQL queries executing attached to them on radio+submit. Stuck at it. @CumminUp07